# Correlation between two random matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I was wondering if there is some mathematical framework to compute the correlation between two $N\times N$ matrices?
For example, the covariance matrix of an $N\times 1$ vector $v$ yields a $N\times N$ matrix $R_{vv}$ where $\{R_{vv}\}_{ij}$ = $E[v(i)v(j)^*]$.
For the case of matrices, I would guess that the result would have dimension $N^2 \times N^2$, similar to a kronecker product, and each element could be brute-forced by doing $N^4$ expectations. But I am not sure of the technical name for such a 'super'matrix/tensor.

**Ideally I am interested in forming MMSE estimates of matrices. Given the joint distribution (or crosscorrelation) of two NxN matrices, what is the MMSE estimate of one matrix conditioned on observing the other matrix?**

If anyone is aware of any exisiting literature on the subject, it would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference, in this context, between a "matrix"  $N\times N$ and a "vector" with $N^2$ components? It's just a list of numbers (?)

Comment: There is no difference actually! The matrix notation is just for convenience of notation. So yes, I can technically form the MMSE estimate I need by forming a $2N^2 \times 1$ vector, observing the first half ($N^2$ values), and forming the conditional estimate of the other $N^2$ values, and then rearranging that into a $N \times N$ matrix. It seems messy though. So if there is a way to keep the variable names in the overall covariance matrix, it would make for a cleaner result.